# No content getting displayed within the Teams meeting interface through Targeted in-meeting notification and in-meeting notification payload

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

Using this sample- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-notification/nodejs , I was trying to generate a dialog in the teams meeting interface. Based on the documentation(referenced below), there are 2 ways to achieve this: i)in-meeting notification payload , ii)Targeted in-meeting notification.

When I used Targeted in-meeting notification, I was able to generate the dialog/adaptive card in the meeting interface but no content got displayed as can be seen on the screenshot after selecting targeted user and clicking on "Send Notification". I tried to display content of this url in the pop up-  https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net/ . I added "azurewebsites.net" in the "validDomains" property in manifest.json but this did not still help.

When I tried using in-meeting notification payload, no popup got displayed in the meeting interface when I clicked on "Push Agenda" as can be seen on the screenshot. However, notification in the form of an adaptive card got sent in the meeting chat as can be seen in the screenshot.

Here is the URL of the repository where you can find my current code- https://github.com/messibarbie/meetings-notification---Issue .  I have noticed that in the .env file, when I run my project locally using teams toolkit in vs code, the BaseUrl stays like this: BaseUrl= <> as can be seen in the dummy env files with dummy values. And even when I do console.log() to print the url, I get <> printed. I am not sure if that is the issue or not. If so, why is not a BaseUrl getting generated?

I can also confirm that I have the bot registered in azure in bot service and an app registration was also created when I ran the project with teams toolkit. What could be the cause of the issues I am having when I used the sample provided by Microsoft as instructed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reference- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/meeting-apps-apis?branch=pr-en-us-7615&tabs=instant-meeting%2Cguest-user%2Cone-on-one-call%2Cdotnet#targeted-meeting-notification-api